# Change in one child layout of listview reflecting in other listview child layouts

Tags: android, listview, layout-inflater

I have created a listview inflating a layout. The inflated layout has a edittext and two buttons which increase and decrease the value in edittext. But the issue is if I change the value of first edittext in listview, the changes get reflected in the fourth edittext(fourth child item) of listview. Similarly the changes in second edittext reflect to fifth edittext and so on. The code I have written to inflate layouts in listview is as below. Please help me to sort out the issue.

```
public class DisplayList extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "main_name";
private static final String TAG_SUBCAT = "cat_name";
private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_RATE = "rate";
private static final String TAG_RATE2 = "rate2";
private static final String TAG_RATE3 = "rate3";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "img";

ImageAdapter mImageAdapter = null;
ListView mListView = null;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
FloatingActionButton fab1;

public  ArrayList<DetailsVO> mListDetails = new ArrayList<DetailsVO>();

String subc;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list);

    myDb=new DatabaseHelper(DisplayList.this);

    fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(DisplayList.this,NewCart.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        subc = extras.getString("Subcat");
    }

    new AsyncCallSoap1().execute();



}

public class AsyncCallSoap1 extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(DisplayList.this);

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        CallSoap com=new CallSoap();
        String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/IprotechService/SelectSuCatgeory";
        String OPERATION_NAME="SelectSuCatgeory";
        String response = com.getDetails(OPERATION_NAME,SOAP_ACTION);

        if(response!=null){
            try {

                JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray(response);

                for(int i=0;i<array1.length();i++)
                {

                    final DetailsVO detailsVO = new DetailsVO();
                    JSONObject obj1 = array1.getJSONObject(i);

                    String out_category = obj1.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
                    String out_subcat = obj1.getString(TAG_SUBCAT);
                    String out_code = obj1.getString(TAG_CODE);
                    String out_name = obj1.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String out_rate = obj1.getString(TAG_RATE);
                    String out_rate2 = obj1.getString(TAG_RATE2);
                    String out_rate3 = obj1.getString(TAG_RATE3);
                    String out_img = obj1.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    if(subc.equalsIgnoreCase(out_subcat)){
                        detailsVO.setImage(out_img);
                        detailsVO.setName(out_name);
                        detailsVO.setRate(out_rate);
                        detailsVO.setRate2(out_rate2);
                        detailsVO.setRate3(out_rate3);

                        mListDetails.add(detailsVO);}
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Showing progress dialog
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

        if(mListDetails != null){
            mImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(DisplayList.this, mListDetails);
            mListView.setAdapter(mImageAdapter);

        }

    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<DetailsVO> mItems;
    private ArrayList<DetailsVO> mOriginalItems;


    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetailsVO> items) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public DetailsVO getItem(int position) {
        return mItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public ArrayList<DetailsVO> getItems(){
        return mItems;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

        }

        DetailsVO detailsVO = mItems.get(position);

        View listView = (View) convertView;

        ImageView image = (ImageView) listView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        final TextView textTitle = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) listView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        Button btnplus = (Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.max);
        Button btnminus = (Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.min);
        final Button btnadd=(Button) listView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btnadd.setClickable(true);

        final TextView quantity = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        ArrayList<String> rate=new ArrayList<String>();

        rate.add("Rs."+detailsVO.getRate());
        if(detailsVO.getRate2()!= null && !detailsVO.getRate2().isEmpty())
        {
            rate.add("Rs."+detailsVO.getRate2());
        }
        if(detailsVO.getRate3()!= null && !detailsVO.getRate3().isEmpty())
        {
            rate.add("Rs."+detailsVO.getRate3());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DisplayList.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,rate);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        btnminus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String value = quantity.getText().toString();
                int quantity1 = Integer.parseInt(value);

                if(quantity1>0)
                {
                    quantity1 = quantity1 -1;

                    String t = Integer.toString(quantity1);
                    quantity.setText(t);
                }
            }
        });


        btnplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String value1 = quantity.getText().toString();
                int quantity2 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
                quantity2 = quantity2 + 1;

                String t=Integer.toString(quantity2);

                quantity.setText(t);
                   }
        });

        final  String u=detailsVO.getImage();
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String im="http://protech.absoftwaresolution.com/img/grocery_imgs/grains/"+u;
                String nm = textTitle.getText().toString();
                String value = quantity.getText().toString();
                int q= Integer.parseInt(value);

                String rate=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String val = rate.substring(rate.lastIndexOf("-")- 1);
                final String val1=rate.substring(3,rate.lastIndexOf("-"));
                int b = Integer.parseInt(val1.trim());
                final int  a= q*b;
                String c=Integer.toString(a);

                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(im,nm,val1,q,a);
                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(DisplayList.this, "Item Added Successfully!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                  }

        });

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load("http://protech.absoftwaresolution.com/img/grocery_imgs/grains/"+detailsVO.getImage())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .into(image);


        textTitle.setText(detailsVO.getName());

        return listView;
    }

}
```

When I click btnplus & btnminus I am changing edittext value which is reflecting in the fourth next edittext in listview

Comment: Use _View Holder_ pattern !

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because your listeners are declared inside the getView(). A ListView recycles views and their references as you scroll up and down. Basically, by the time you click on something in that first row, the ListView will have changed those references to some other object. Without a view ID or tag to track it down with, those clicks go elsewhere.

The way I'd try to solve this is by declaring an OnItemClickListener outside the adapter for your listview items. Inside that, detect which subview (button +/-) is being clicked, and then adjust your String accordingly. Once you have a reference to the container/ViewGroup, you should be set...

Comment: Thank you, I'll make changes accordingly